# How to convert python YOLO-V5 into exe execution file

Tags: python, exe, yolov5

I encountered this problem. I mainly wanted to convert YOLO-V5's detect.py program into an exe executable file. However, after I used pyinstaller to convert the py program into exe, I found that some packages were missing. I added the missing packages. After finishing the process, the exe executable file can run but it says that the specified file path cannot be found: **D:..\yolo\dist\detect\utils\general.pyc**

Tried methods:

1. I saw the general.py file in the utils folder of YOLO-V5, and there is a general.cpython-37.pyc file under the *pycache* folder. I tried to put it under the utils folder and changed the name Change to general.pyc, but the converted EXE program will crash with the error:

**unicodedecodeerror: 'utf-8' codec cannot decode byte 0xe7 in position 9: invalid contiguous bytes**

As a result, the model cannot be inferred in the end.

Comment: Please call out some specifics. The first "error" you show is not an error but just simply a path to a pyc file. Please clarify the question. If the purpose is converting the application to an executable, what are you trying to use to do this? Provide examples of what you have tried to the community.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reminder. I have restated the problem and the method used.